# square roots of 1, congruences

Tags: number-theory

Show that the congruence:

$$x^2  - 1  ≡  0(2^s)$$
has only $4$ solutions if $s\ge3$ .  I can find $4$ solutions, but want to show there are no more.

Yet, if $2$ is replaced by an odd prime there are only $2$ solutions, $1$ and $-1$.
(That seems to be based on the fact that if $x$ is a solution of the 
congruence:

$$x^2  - 1  ≡  0(p^s)$$, for $p$ an odd prime and $s>1$, it is also a solution of

$$x^2 - 1 ≡  0(p)$$
This doesn't seem to depend on $p$ being odd.

What am I missing?

Comment: The only even prime is $2$, and $1 \equiv -1 \bmod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

We want $2^s$ to divide $(x-1)(x+1)$. Note that $x-1$ and $x+1$ are even. Since they differ by $2$, one of them is divisible by $2$ but by no higher power of $2$, and the other is divisible by $2^{s-1}$.

Let us take the case $x-1$ divisible by $2$ but by no higher power of $2$, and you can take care of the other case.

So $x+1$ has to be divisible by $2^{s-1}$. Thus $x=-1+k\cdot 2^{s-1}$ for some integer $k$. If $k$ is odd, that gives the solution $x\equiv -1+2^{s-1}\pmod{2^s}$. If $k$ is even that gives the solution $x\equiv -1\pmod{2^s}$.

The reason that we need $s\ge 3$ is that if $s\le 2$ the "four" roots we have found will not be distinct modulo $2^s$.

**Remark:** The difference between $2$ and an odd prime $p$ is that $2$ can divide **both** $x-1$ and $x+1$, while an odd prime cannot.

Comment: It seems that the theorem:

Comment: Your previous message has only "But where is the flaw in saying" so I do not know what is being asked.

Comment: I type slowly and my comment timed out.  It seems that the theorem:
If d|m, d >0,  and if u is a solution of f(x)≡0(modm)
i
then u is a solution of f(x)≡0(mod  d)

plays no role in the case where m=2 while it does if m=P^s, p an odd prime.
I think there may be more to this.  The non trivial roots in the case p=2 turn out to be congruent mod 2^(s-1) to trivial roots.
 
(As you may have guessed I am a beginner in number theory,working my way through Niven et al; I've worked in group representations and special functions.)

Comment: The theorem you mention applies equally well to powers of $2$. One difference, for the polynomial congruence $x^2-a\equiv 0\pmod{p^s}$ is that Hensel lifting (you may have gotten to it) works smoothly for powers of odd primes, but is messier for powers of $2$, since the derivative $2x$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $2$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a non trivial theorem which you could use. Notice any such $x$ must have odd residue mod $2^{s}$. Now, if $s \geq 3$, $(\mathbf{Z}/2^{s}\mathbf{Z})^{*} \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/2^{s-3} \mathbf{Z}$. This group has 3 elements of order 2.